# ICE-Emergency contacts

Tags: phone-app, emergency-calls

Need Help - How to remove contacts from Emergency list
I have S5 , I have added couple of numbers under “ICE-Emergency contacts “ groups. Its was displaying under Emergency Contacts.

Now I want to remove those names form emergency list . ..opened contacts and removed the names from that group but those numbers are not getting removed the screen ( Local Phone and Click Emergency call) same list is getting displayed .

Even restart of the device is also not working .. Any idea how to remove the numbers from that group.

Answer (score 1):

On the Samsung Galaxy S3, you have to do this from the Contact, and re-save.
From the ICE list that contains the contact, click the contact and Edit it (S3 uses a pencil Icon to indicate editing). See the Groups area for the contact, and uncheck. Save the Contact/Group association. Save (again) for the Contact.

The contact should now show as removed from the ICE list.

Comment: Thanks. In fact on the Samsung Galaxy SIII, from the `Contacts -> Groups -> ICE - emergency contacts` screen you can simply tap a contact, and then from the `Groups` section of that contact you can click on `ICE - emergency contacts, My contacts`, and then uncheck the checkbox next to `ICE - emergency contacts` and click on `Save` to remove the contact from the ICE emergency contacts list. Regards.